# document.frames is undefined Error in Chrome and FF

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, web

hey i have some code that i get Error "document.frames is undefined"
in IE it work fine. not in Chrome and FF.

```js
topAppFrame.document.frames["SlipArea"].location = target;
```

target = SlipArea.aspx

topAppFrame = Window → Login.aspx

any idea? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

There is not such property.
Use `window.frames` instead.

```
window.frames["SlipArea"].src = target;
```

Comment: `document.frames` is defined in older versions of Internet Explorer and I understand that does not behave the same way as `window.frames`. See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/ms537459%28v=vs.94%29?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Answer (score 0):

top.frames["SlipArea"].href= target;

work to me!